# Any way to get JsDoc help in IntelliJ when documenting AMD modules?

Tags: intellij-idea, amd, webstorm, jsdoc

I like using JsDoc, as it gives me a lot of help when using WebStorm (or other IntelliJ derivates), such as parameter lookup, quick access to documentation, etc.

Most examples assume that you can write something like

```
/** @class MyClass */
var MyClass = function() {
}
```

But if you wrap your code in anonymous functions to avoid polluting the namespace (say, due to concatenating the js files), then WebStorm no longer finds the documentation, and I no longer get much help.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: please look at [WEB-7868](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-7868) and [WEB-7834](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-7834) - do they look similar to your issue? If not, can you provide a sample that shows up your problem?

Comment: will be back with more info after the weekend :)